# Why are the logos from some ubuntu related sites and askubuntu so similar?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that the logos and fav icons from sites like askubuntu.com and omgubuntu.co.uk are almost the same.

Are they connected in any ways? Is there a specific reason they would look so similar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The little bubble is part of the design guidelines, check it out here:

- http://design.canonical.com/the-toolkit/brand-communication-guide/ ([archive link for the PDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20111028170932/http://design.canonical.com/brand/A.%20Brand_Communication_Guide_v1.pdf) on Wayback Machine)

Comment: That simple! ;) thanks