# What's the meaning of the Ask Ubuntu logo?

Tags: discussion

> The Super User version: [Super User logo meaning](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14360/super-user-logo-meaning)

There is always a meaning to the logos of certain brands.

Does Ask Ubuntu have a meaning to its logo? It has a bubble in it and also the Ubuntu logo at its top-right corner, but what does that mean exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logo is the name of the site, with the word "ask" in a speech bubble like that of a cartoon character speaking. I don't think there's anything else to add, really. It's sort of what you see is what you get.

Comment: The bubble's from Canonical's early design guidelines: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1969/158442